# Validation rule for text field - It should accept only numeric value and accepts only 12 or 13 digits

Tags: validation-rule

Note : We can't change the field type to number because it is existing field.

Comment: NOT(ISNUMBER(Envent_A__c )  && ( LEN(Envent_A__c ) >=  4 && LEN(Envent_A__c ) <= 8))

Comment: You should add this information to your question by making an [edit]. Comments are best thought of as temporary, and their limited length and formatting options generally make it harder for others to incorporate into answers or replies.

Comment: If your required length is 12-13 characters, why is your validation rules to reject only 4-8 character length strings?

Answer (score 2):

you can try following:

```
    or(
      NOT(ISNUMBER(Text__c )),

      AND(
         LEN(Text__c ) != 12,
         LEN(Text__c ) != 13
     )
   )
```

Cheers Rainer

Answer (score 0):

Text field that you created, provide 13 value (so that it can take maximum of 13 characters in it) as Length and mentioning about that it should contain only the numeric value, we can write the validation as:

> NOT(ISNUMBER(TextField))

Let me know this helps!